# Az disk delete not deleting the disk

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to delete a disk in a resource group that my account has permission to delete. When running this command no errors happen and the script finishes, but the disk is not deleted when checking the portal (-n and -g are filled in with correct information in the actual code).

`az disk delete -n "DiskName" -g ResourceGroup --yes`

Comment: Double check to make sure you are on the latest version of the CLI.  One easy way to test is to use CloudShell which is evergreen.

Comment: @KenWMSFT Thanks for the response, I checked and it does look like I'm on the latest CLI version - 2.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `--verbose` or `--debug` parameter for full debug logs.